# kill an Activity after a certain time

Tags: android, timer, runnable

Im working on a Quiz App. in which I have a different types of quizzes. `Quiz with Time and Quiz without Time`. Quiz without time is simple and there is no certain or specific time given to attempt the quiz. But the Quiz with Time is time restricted Quiz.

**`What I Want:`**

When an individual try to attempt a time restricted quiz. The certain amount of time will be show on an activity for instance remaining time (30 min left). and after the **30th min** the activity automatically **stop**. I have tried **`timer class`** but that is used for delay.

how can I stop a activity after a certain time?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can go for CountDown Timer. Check this tutorial: http://androidsolution4u.blogspot.in/2012/12/android-count-down-timer.html

Answer (score 2):

```
    public void countDown() {
    new CountDownTimer(60000*30, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            int seconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60 ;
            int minutes = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / (1000*60)) % 60);
            int hours   = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / (1000*60*60)) % 24);                
            String my_new_str =((((((((( (pad(hours)+":"+pad(minutes)+":"+pad(seconds)));
            timer.setText( my_new_str);     
            float pvalue =  ( float)(millisUntilFinished*100)/(60000*30);               
            myprogressbar.setProgress((int)(Math.round(pvalue)));
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            timer.setText("Completed");
            goToResult();
            this,finish();
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this using Handlers

try some thing like this...

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable x=new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            finish();
          }         
        };
    handler.postDelayed(x, 6000);
```

Comment: i think this is for the delay to go from currrent activity to another activity

Answer (score 0):

Put your question in `Thread`...

```
Thread t=new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try{
                    sleep(30000);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, Login.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try to use AsyncTask or Handler in your Activity. i think you set some certain time limits for the 
    Quiz Question so please make sure to use any one of this above i mentioned.

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable x=new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                   Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, TargetActivity.class);
                  startActivity(intent);
                finish();// activity will kill. or use 
                System.Exit();
              }         
            };
        handler.postDelayed(x, yourtimelimit(in timemills or millisecond)); 


  Even you doesn't work yet means try to use onComplete listener and the put it finish in that method or 
use onDestroy method inside to finish().
    thank you
```

Comment: isn't this snippet is for delay? means to say goes from one activity to another activity?

Comment: tell your pblm clearly you wanna go to another activity while countdown time reached 00 means is it rite??

Comment: well my problem is when the quiz starts the countdown is also start with it. for instance we have 10 questions and we have 5 minutes to attempt these question. if we wouldn't attempt all questions then quiz will automatically stop and then the further process. you could say the result.

Comment: thats fine so try to set 5mins in millisecond of this handler and use finish method and also your further works.